# Opening private chrome window using automation tool UiPath

Tags: automation, cross-browser, uipath

I want to open the private browser in order to open a website. How will I be able to do it using chrome browser ?

Can you provide me some steps that I should follow in order to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to open the browser in private mode, you just have to tick the checkbox named **private** which will be found in the **options** menu

Refer the screenshot below

[image]